# Correcting harmonics for power factor correction

Tags: reactive-power

Is it recommended to use **LINE REACTORS** to mitigate harmonic issues on a power distribution system if there are power factor capacitors installed?

Comment: Way to broad! Give a specific example.

Comment: Ok this factory has harmonic current below the 15% threshold that's nessecary to be concerned about however whenever the power caps lock in the harmonic current jump sky high. I wanna control the excess harmonic current

Comment: Edit your question to add relevant detail, don't reply in comments. And while you're about it fix the spelling of 'hormonic'.

Comment: Also "sky high" is not a recognised engineering quantity. It will be somewhere between 0 and 100%. This is an engineering site so please use numbers.

Comment: **Don't!** Leave this to someone who doesn't have to ask this question on a site like this. This is inherently difficult to do, and even transmission system operators (that's the guys/gals who control the entire grid), makes mistakes when attempting to do this. I know of reactors in industrial plants that are out of operation because the engineers responsible didn't have the necessary skills to design it. I don't mean to be rude here, but you shouldn't make someone pay _a lot_, for something that might work. Reactors alone might help, but it might also make matters worse!

Answer (score 1):

Line reactors can be installed at the input to individual non-linear loads to reduce harmonic currents. Harmonic filters could also be used for individual non-linear loads.

Harmonic resonance in the power distribution system can be reduced by changing the natural frequency of the system, but that may be difficult to accomplish. The effects of harmonic currents in the distribution system can be reduced by installing harmonic traps. It may be possible to add reactors to system power factor capacitor banks to convert them to harmonic traps.

In systems where harmonic problems are evident, it will probably be necessary to perform a harmonic analysis of the entire system. You will need to find detailed reference material explaining how to perform an analysis and design or select a mitigation system.

Comment: +1. Good answer! _"harmonic analysis of the entire system"_ [...] you also need to either: Get detailed data about the harmonic distribution of the drawn/produced current from the suppliers of large rectifiers of converters in the system, or: Measure the level of the individual harmonics at various places in the system using for instance a Fluke 41B. You then have to find the natural frequency/frequencies, and check if large harmonics appear at those frequencies. If that's the case, then you might insert a harmonic filter (reactors+coils) to change the natural frequency to a non critical one.